# How do I access Azure Key Vault Secret in .NET Core 2.2 console app?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core

I have the following code in my Program.cs file in a console app that is hosted in AKS.

```
private IConfigurationRoot _configurationRoot;

        private IConfigurationRoot ConfigurationRoot
        {
            get
            {
                if (_configurationRoot == null)
                {
                    var deployedEnv = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DeploymentEnv");

                    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{deployedEnv}.json", true);

                    _configurationRoot = builder.Build();

#if DEBUG
                    _configurationRoot = builder.AddAzureKeyVault(_configurationRoot["AzureKeyVaultURL"]).Build();
#else
                    _configurationRoot = builder.AddAzureKeyVault(_configurationRoot["AzureKeyVaultURL"], _configurationRoot["AzureKeyVaultClientId"], _configurationRoot["AzureKeyVaultClientSecret"]).Build();
#endif
                }

                return _configurationRoot;
            }
        }
```

I am getting the following error regarding the client secret and I am not sure why. I am following a similar implementation in our web services without issue. Any idea what the root cause is? I have been through many console app configuration posts/tutorials but have not found an answer. Thank you!

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: clientSecret
at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVaultConfigurationExtensions.AddAzureKeyVault(IConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder, String vault, String clientId, String clientSecret, IKeyVaultSecretManager manager)
at GlobalCustomerIdUpdater.Updaters.GlobalCustomerIdUpdater.get_ConfigurationRoot() in /src/GlobalCustomerIdUpdater/Updaters/GlobalCustomerIdUpdateCoordinator.cs:line 37
at GlobalCustomerIdUpdater.Updaters.GlobalCustomerIdUpdater.get_AppointmentDatabaseConnectionFactory() in /src/GlobalCustomerIdUpdater/Updaters/GlobalCustomerIdUpdateCoordinator.cs:line 66
at GlobalCustomerIdUpdater.Updaters.GlobalCustomerIdUpdater.Update() in /src/GlobalCustomerIdUpdater/Updaters/GlobalCustomerIdUpdateCoordinator.cs:line 95
```

Comment: How is the console app supposed to authenticate when in debug mode if you don't provide the credentials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code:

```
#if DEBUG
                    _configurationRoot = builder.AddAzureKeyVault(_configurationRoot["AzureKeyVaultURL"]).Build();
#else
                    _configurationRoot = builder.AddAzureKeyVault(_configurationRoot["AzureKeyVaultURL"], _configurationRoot["AzureKeyVaultClientId"], _configurationRoot["AzureKeyVaultClientSecret"]).Build();
#endif
```

In DEBUG mode, only `AzureKeyVaultURL` is set in configuration, that might be the root cause of your issue.

By the way, the stack trace shows that the error occurs in `GlobalCustomerIdUpdater`. Could you please provide more codes about it?